# SQLite, Automatically update field in table after insert in another table

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I'm a newbie in databases, so I apologize in advance if this question is about something easy and obvious but I'm not able to figure alone.
Basically, I'm trying to do what follows (for educational purpose, nothing related to anything "serious"):

I have a table `courses` where each course has

- an id
- a name
- the total number of people enrolled.

Then I have a table of `people`, each of them has

- an id
- a name
- a `course_id`

(assuming each person can only enroll in one
course). The `course_id`  is a foreign key related to the id of the course.

What I'd like to know is how to automatically update the number of people enrolled in a course whenever I insert a row in `people` (increment the number of people enrolled in the specific course the added person is enrolled to).

I read I can do that using triggers but I didn't actually understood how. Anyway I'm querying the db from javascript so basically I'd like to only pass the `INSERT` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `AFTER INSERT` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_people_ins AFTER INSERT ON people
BEGIN
  UPDATE courses 
  SET total = COALESCE(total, 0) + 1 
  WHERE id = NEW.course_id;
END;
```

Change `total` to the actual name of the column in `courses`.
If the default vale of `total` is `0` then you don't need `COALESCE()`, so change to:

```
SET total = total + 1
```